# Long code that needs to wrap

Tags: line-breaking, pseudocode

How would I enter this text on an 8.5x11 worksheet with 1.25inch margins all around so wraps around and does not extend onto the margins? Using normalsize text.

```
SolverAdd CellRef:=Worksheets("Worksheet_Alpha_Gamma_TestResult").Range("$H$43:$H$46")Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,letterpaper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
SolverAdd CellRef:=Worksheets("Worksheet_Alpha_Gamma_TestResult").Range("$H$43:$H$46")Relation:=5, FormulaText:="binary
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

`breaklines=true` allows for line-breaking within the `lstlistings` environment. I used `basicstyle=\ttfamily`, although that is not necessary.

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text, while [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used to obtain the layout requirements.